# Getting child editorGrid types in a FormPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

Inside my extjs `FormPanel`, I have several editor grids. I don't know what the IDs of these grids are, so I can't use `Ext.getCmp`.

What is the best way to say 'Get all the `editorgrid` types that are in this `FormPanel`'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the `items` collection of the FormPanel by the type of each item by using `isXType`:

```
var grids = formPanel.items.filterBy(function (item) {
    return item.isXType("editorgrid");
});
```

`grids` will be a new collection of all the `EditorGridPanel` items.

**Update:** A more concise way:

```
var grids = formPanel.findByType("editorgrid", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though we avoid hardcoding DOM IDs, having component IDs available can be handy.

```
this.gridOneId = Ext.id( null, 'gridOne' );  // guaranteed unique
new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        id: this.gridOneId,
        store: storeOne,
        columns: columnsOne,
        title: 'Grid One',
```

...
        });

```
this.gridTwoId = Ext.id( null, 'gridTwo' );  // guaranteed unique
new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        id: this.gridTwoId,
        store: storeTwo,
        columns: columnsTwo,
        title: 'Grid Two',
```

...
        });